# Swift: programmatically add UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, click, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this code block, but it does not work the way I want to. datum_view appear good, but to no avail I click on it, it does not work.

Update code:

[Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5r8U.png)

```
var containerView: UIView!
var tov_datum = [String]()
var datum_view: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    containerView = UIView()

    let SCREEN_SIZE = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


    var Y: CGFloat = 0

    for index in tov_datum {
        datum_view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, Y, SCREEN_SIZE.width, 80))
        let gradientView = GradientView(frame: datum_view.bounds)
        datum_view.insertSubview(gradientView, atIndex: 0)

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"klikk:")
        datum_view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        datum_view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        containerView.addSubview(datum_view)


        Y = Y + 80
    }
    let YY = tov_datum.count * 80
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: vetítésekView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute:.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:CGFloat(YY)).active = true

    vetítésekView.addSubview(containerView)
}


func klikk(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("BOOOOYAAAA")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like the size of `containerView` is set anywhere. To quickly see if that's the problem, initialize it with the frame you're creating `datum_view` inside:

```
let SCREEN_SIZE = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
containerView = UIView(frame: SCREEN_SIZE)
```

If that works, then figure out what size you actually want containerView to be and set up appropriate constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
func klikk(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

to

```
func klikk(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("klikk:"))
```

to :

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"klikk:")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should declare your tapGestureRecognizer 
as a property.

Comment: I missed that it all work in cycle, in this case I would recommend you to add a clear button on every datum_view you created.

Comment: Has been tired to add clear button, on every datum_view, it did not work.

Comment: let Button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: SCREEN_SIZE.width-8, height: 76))
            Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FilmekMusoronVC.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

datum_view.addSubview(Button)

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("BOOOOYAAAA")
    }